# Synchronizing Slides and Video-Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, powerpoint, flowplayer

I am making a rails app to synchronize a given video and powerpoint presentation. The slides are stored in img format and am using flowplayer for rendering the video. Any idea how i can synchronize the slides with the video?

Sorry if the question sounds silly.I am still a rails noob!